# Paragraph line alignment XML

Tags: android, xml

I have an XML file like this:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My Application</string>

    <string name="mytext">Some long line\n
        Some long line\n
        Some long line\n
        Some long line\n
    </string>

</resources>
```

In which I have some long lines of text I want to display but the XML produces the following output on screen:

[image]

Why are the rest of the lines after first not aligned with first line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem can be solved by preceding `\n`. Something like this:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">MyProj</string>
<string name="mytext">Some long line
    \nSome long line
    \nSome long line
    \nSome long line
</string>
```

I think the trailing `\n` were causing the problem.

Comment: Exactly, what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

remove `SPACE` after the each `\n`

following format should be work.

```
<string name="mytext">Some long line\nSome long line\nSome long line\nSome long line\n</string>
```

**EDIT 1**

> activity.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:padding="3dp"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <TextView 
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:background="#535353"
       android:textColor="#ffffff"
       android:text="@string/mytext"
       android:textSize="20dp"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

> Screenshot

[image: Ouput]

Comment: What if I want to write it as a paragraph in XML rather than one long string? It won't work at all?

Comment: If it's help means kindly accept the answer. then only others can easily/quickly find the correct answer

Comment: In `strings.xml` can I write "Some long line\nSome long line\n" as a paragrapgh rather than a one long string?

Comment: yeah. you can try and let me know if any problem

Answer (score -1):

You can write like this... whatever (space, new line) you have given inside **CDATA** will be considered.

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">My Application</string>
<string name="mytext">
<![CDATA[Some long line
Some long line
Some long line]]>
</string>
</resources>
```